# Binding a Nested Object in ASP.NET MVC - Razor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-binding

My ASP.NET MVC viewmodel is designed as below

```
public class Customer
{
  public int CustomerId{ get; set; }
  public string CustomerName{ get; set; }
  public Address CustomerAddress {get;set;}
}


 public class Address
{
   public int AddressId{ get; set; }
   public string HouseName{ get; set; }
   public string Location{get;set;}
}
```

How can I bind Address object properly in cshtml page so that it should be available after form Submit.

In cshtml page I want bind it the properties as below

```
 @model CustomerManagement.Model.ViewModels.Customers.Customer
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form- 
   control readOnlySchdCode", @readonly = "readonly" } })
    @Html.Hidden("AddressId", Model.Address.AddressId)
    @Html.Hidden("HouseName", Model.Address.HouseName)
   }
```

In controller form submit will look like as below

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddCustomer(Customer model)
    {
       //How can i access Address properties eg:model.CustomerAddress.AddressId??
    }
```

Can anyone share a sample code on how to bind the Above viewmodel properly in cshtml using razor template and how properties are properly retrieved in Action method while form submit.

Comment: Have you tried using a Helper Model means a model combination of Customer and Address?

Comment: @ashhadullah..I am not familiar with that..Can you please explain

Comment: Hello Is there anything else I can help you with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this way.

**Client side:**

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
@using WebAppDemo.Models
@model WebAppDemo.Models.Customer

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddCustomer", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Form1" }))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">Cust Id</div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.CustomerId, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">Customer Name</div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.CustomerName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">Address</div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.CustomerAddress.HouseName, new { @class = "form-control" }) 
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12"><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"></div>

    </div>
}
```

**Form Output Should Be Like:**

[image]

**Controller:**

```
        [HttpPost] //attribute to get posted values from HTML Form
        public  ActionResult AddCustomer(Customer model)
        {
            return Ok();// For testing I just kept it as `Ok` You can return `View()`;
        }
```

> **Note:** Please try to pass value on form as per `Model property` descriptions. Other than you might
> get `null` value.

**Output:**

[image]

Hope it will help you. Let me know if you have any further concern.

Comment: So in ViewModel side there is no change required ??How the binding happens on Address object ..So if i am setting hidden field as @Html.Hidden("AddressId", Model.Address.AddressId)..then is it available while Submit ??

Comment: No need to change your model. You can keep that as it is, I just made this example keeping all of your code.

Comment: Just copy as paste my sample it will work exactly, I am here no worries just let me know if you encountered any more issue.

Comment: if i set @Html.Hidden("AddressId", Model.CustomerAddress.AddressId)..then is it available in action method as model.CustomerAddress.AddressId ??

Comment: No it will throw an exception. because on load value would be empty that's why.

Comment: May I know what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I hope if I set Location as @Html.Hidden( Model.CustomerAddress.Location, new { @id = "addressLocation" }) in html page, then it will be accessed on action method after submitting like  model.CustomerAddress.Location..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little example

```
    public class BigViewModel : IModelOptions
    {
       public bool Confirm { get; set; }
       public SmallViewModel SmallView { get; set; }
    }

    public class SmallViewModel
    {
       public string Stuff{ get; set; }
    }

    public interface IModelOptions
    {
       SmallViewModel SmallView { get; set; }
    }
```

and our controller would be like

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
          return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(BigViewModel model)
        {
           var smallVIewModelInfo = model.SmallView.Stuff;
           var bigViewModelConfirm = model.Confirm;
           return View();
        }
    }
```

using view like

```
    @model MvcApplication1.Models.BigViewModel
```